# Derivative of a function evaluated at some point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

I just want to be sure about this:

If I have a differentiable function $f(x)$, then $f'(p)$ (or the nth derivative of f at $p$),which $p$ is where the nth derivative is being evaluated, should I consider $f'(p)$ as a constant or not?

Also, does it differ when I do not know exactly the value of $p$? I mean, I'm just sure that $p$ is a point where $f$ is defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of a function at a point by definition is the slope of the line tangent to the curve at the point. Then if $ p $ is a constant $ f'(p) $ is also a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did not know how to write in such a way. Now, about the answer: so this also extends to higher derivatives at p, right?

Comment: Of course, if $p$ is constant, then $f^n(p)$ is also constant.